# New to using functions in Python

Tags: python, function

I am trying to understand why `newNameList` is not defined:

```
ListofNames1 = ['Mark', 'Andrew']

ListofNames2 = ['Anjela', 'Lora']

names = ListofNames1

def greeting(names):
    newNameList = []
    for item in names:
        newNameList.append(str(names))
    return (names)
print(greeting(names))

def function2(newNameList):
    for each in newNameList:
        newNameList2.append(newNameList.upper())
    return (newNameList2)

print(function2(newNameList))
```

The output

```
['Mark', 'Andrew']
...
NameError: name 'newNameList' is not defined.
```

The name error occurs on the last line in the code.

Comment: Perhaps providing some more context would be useful so here isthe code:

Comment: def greeting(names): newNameList = [] for item in names: newNameList.append(str(names)) return (names) print(greeting(names)) def function2(newNameList): for each in newNameList: newNameList2.append(newNameList.upper()) return (newNameList2) print(function2(newNameList)) The output ['Mark', 'Andrew'] newNameList2.append(newNameList.upper()) return (newNameList2) ---> print(function2(newNameList)) NameError: name 'newNameList' is not defined So I am not sure what I am missing there

Comment: Please add your code to your question and format it correctly to allow users to help you. Else, it's simply impossible to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newNameList` is only defined within the scope of `function2`.  Since the `print` statement is  not indented at the same level of `function2` then `newNameList` is not visible to it.  The three variables defined at a top-level scope are `ListofNames1`, `ListofNames1`, and `names`.  These are the only three variables that can be passed to `function2` in the `print` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do it.

For example:

```py
def use_greeting_function(name):
   new_list_name = greeting(name)
```

Now `new_list_name` has the output of `greeting` function and you can use it in the function afterwards.

Comment: def greeting(names):
    newNameList = []  
    for item in names:  
        newNameList.append(str(names))  
    return (names)
print(greeting(names))
def function2(newNameList):
    for each in newNameList:  
        newNameList2.append(newNameList.upper())
    return (newNameList2)
print(function2(newNameList))

The output 
['Mark', 'Andrew']
    newNameList2.append(newNameList.upper())
return (newNameList2)
---> print(function2(newNameList))
NameError: name 'newNameList' is not defined
So I am not sure what I am missing there

Comment: add the code with proper formatting in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, legit my first time using this, maybe look at the image I just uploaded helps ?

Thank you for your time though

Answer (score 0):

```
NameError: name 'newNameList' is not defined.
```

tells you what's wrong. You should have defined `newNameList` outside the `greetings()` function.

I have rewritten your code:

```python
ListofNames1 = ['Mark', 'Andrew']
ListofNames2 = ['Anjela', 'Lora']
names = ListofNames1

newNameList = []

def greeting(names):
    for item in names:
        newNameList.append(names)

    return names

print(greeting(names))


def function2(newNameList):
    newNameList2 = []

    for each in newNameList:
        newNameList2.append(str(newNameList).upper())

    return newNameList2

print(function2(newNameList))
```

And using the `upper()` method on a list doesn't work. Convert it to `str` first.